# Finding perfect subsets

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongo-java-driver

We have requests collection :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("xxxxxx"),
    "requestId" : "REQ4",
    "scrips" : "[3553, 5647]"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("xxxxxx"),
    "requestId" : "REQ1",
    "scrips" : "[0001]"
}
```

and Scrips collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("xxxx"),
    "scrip" : "0001"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("xxxx"),
    "scrip" : "0456"
}
```

We need to get a list of all requests in requests collection - who have  scrips as a complete subset of the scrip collections.

Expected output : `['REQ1']`

How do we achieve this in the most efficient way?
We are using java mongo driver 3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, try saving scrips in request collection as an array of string instead of a string of array-like ["3553"] making it:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("xxxxxx"),
    "requestId" : "REQ4",
    "scrips" : ["3553", "5647"]
}
```

After that, you can use below to maintain an array of all scrips from scrip collection:

```
let allScrips=await scrips.aggregate([
  {$group:{
   _id:null,scrips:{$addToSet:"$scrip"}
  }}
])
```

After that use $setIsSubset in the aggregate pipeline to compare above allScrips[0].scrips array with request collection's scrips only if allScrips.length comes

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/

```
let requestsWithScrips=await requests.aggregate([
  { $project: {requestId:1,isSubset: { $setIsSubset: [ "$scrips",allScrips[0].scrips] }}},
  { $match:{isSubset:true}}
])
```

Comment: How to achieve this in one single pipeline aggregate operation across 2 collections

Comment: For that try 
let requests=await requests.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      scrips: 1,
      scripsSize: {
        $size: "$scrips"
      },
      requestId: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "scrips",
      localField: "scrips",
      foreignField: "scrip",
      as: "populatedScrips"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      requestId: 1,
      scripsSize: 1,
      popScripsSize: {
        $size: "$populatedScrips"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      scripsSize: {
        $eq: "$popScripsSize"
      }
    }
  }
])

Comment: In the above comment, we calculate the size of the array in requests collection and then lookup/populate scrips from scrip collection if after populate size of both array is equal means all scrips of JSON in request exists in scrips collection else it doesn't and will not be returned

Comment: misses the addtoset operation

Comment: In the previous answer, I was checking if scrips in request was subset of all scrips or not, while in above case we're checking if after population size of both populated and un-populated array remains equal then requests' scrips exist in scrip collection that's why no use of $addToSet required here

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/index.html
addToSet is used to make an array of unique scrips from scrips database

Comment: $lookup: { from: "scrips", localField: "scrips", foreignField: "scrip"<=would this work?localfield is an array ,while foreignfield is document key in a collection.We are checking if all elements in an array are present as document values in a collection

Comment: Yes, it'll work here's a link for reference:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#use-lookup-with-an-array

Comment: Unfortunately it isnt working for me as populatedScrips always returns an empty array.Is it possible through addtoset and setissubset ?

Comment: can you double-check if scrips in requests are not a string of array but an array of strings and local filed, foreign field, from(collection name) are correct?

Comment: { "requestId" : "REQ4", "scripcount" : 2, "matched" : 2 } - reached upto this.However,the last match  - Aggregates.match(eq("$scripcount","$matched")) - seems to suppress the output completely.Whats it meant to do.

Comment: last $match is used to check if scrips array size in requests collection and populated scrips array size are equal meaning they all exist in scrips collection only then return data

Comment: Try replacing last $match with
{$match:{$expr:{$eq:["$scripcount","$matched"]}}}